# Yii2: Is it possible to set visibile default value for an Autocomplete Widget?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, yii2

I initialize a model, and one attribute of it, on my controller

```
$model = new MyModel;
$model->internal_code = 'BAUBAU';
```

Then I populate an array of codes suitable for autocomplete

```
$products = Product::find()
                ->select([
                        Product::tableName().'.id as id',
                        'internal_code as label',
                        'internal_code as value',
                    ])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
```

Then I'd like to use an autocomplete to show the default value AND allow user to change it selecting via autocomplete widget.

This the View code

```
echo $form->field($model, 'internal_code')
    ->widget(AutoComplete::classname(),[
        'clientOptions' => [
                'source'    => $products
            ]
        ])
    ->label('Internal code');
```

Actually the widget works, user can digit chars and select from the results of autocomplete narrowed search.

Bu the problem is that even if `$model->internal_code` is set, the widget, at loading, do not shows the value. **The user don't see the default value ('BAUBAU') on screen.** I'm not able to understand what property and/or client option to fill.

Note: I added `jquery-ui` tag because this Yii2 widget uses the autocomplete widget of JqueryUI

Comment: @gamitg: extended explanation of case and problem. I hope it's enough. The problem is simple: how to show the field value in the autocomplete widget.

Comment: 1. Is BAUBAU part of $products? 2. Shouldn't $products be simple string array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set [value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-inputwidget.html#$value-detail) property.

Like this.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'internal_code')
    ->widget(AutoComplete::classname(),[
        'value' => (!empty($model->internal_code) ? $model->internal_code : ''),
        'clientOptions' => [
                'source'    => $products
         ]
 ])->label('Internal code');
```

Answer (score 0):

default value you can set in options array, view below:

```
'options' => [
                    'placeholder'=> 'Select...',
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'value' => (!empty($model->attribute) ? $model->attribute : ''),
            ],
```